Can I omit Makefile.in from version control if it's generated from Makefile.am?
My project contains 1 binary and 14 subprojects.
Each one is located in its own folder.
Each folder have Makefile.am, Makefile.in, and then in the Debug/Release folders in the top of the tree there are 15 folders with the Makefiles.
Now the latter will definitely not be in the version control as they will be continuosly changed and depend n the different OS/build system.
Now my understanding is that Makefile.am will be written by me by modifying different rules and include headers/libraries fr the dependencies of my project. And so this file has to be in the version control - Git.
Now the Makefile.in file is made during the autoreconf phase and so it will be regenerated each time my software will be build. And so it shouldn't be in the version control - Git.
Am I correct? Can I safely remove Makefile.in and add it to the .gitignore file?

If indeed it is generated from another file then yes, you don't need or want to put it in version control.

This is a matter of opinion.  There are those who hold that generated artifacts should not be put under source control, that being redundant.  However, if the source control system is also used as a distribution system, as is common these days, then additional considerations apply.  Per GNU and me, distributions of Autotools-based projects should include Autotools-generated artifacts such as Makefile.in, so that those who want only to build the project, not modify it, do not require the autotools to do so.

@JohnBollinger, understood. However, those auto-generated files will be changed if the distro maintainers will rebuild the distribution. So why they should be kept? Especially since there are differences from distro to distro in terms of what is stable.

@Igor, to make sure we're on the same page: my "distribution" above is simply distributing the project software to others.  Your use of the term "distro maintainers" makes me suspect that you're thinking more along the lines of a Linux "distribution", which is a curated collection of multiple packages.  The point is that the autogenerated files may be changed by the project's maintainers in the normal course of developing and maintaining the project, but they are not (don't need to be) modified by people who just want to build the project, such as the maintainers of a Linux distribution.

Makefile.in is input file that is indeed generated from autotools user created Makefile.am so it is safe to not include it in version control check-in.
One consideration should be that Makefile.in is input file used by configure script to generate the final Makefile; so configure script should be removed from version control too to make sure the clone is not "defunct" (does not come with configure script that fails because Makefile.in is missing).
The right thing is to have only *.am files checked in and after checkout run whatever command (e.g. autoreconf) that generates final configure script (and all .in files on the way).

If the project is distributed in source code form as a tarball or zip file, I think it is common practice to run automake, and then include Makefile.in and the configure script in these archives.

Not only is that common, @j6t, but the Autotools' built in mechanism for building distribution tarballs does it automatically, and the docs devote some space specifically to why that should be so.

It is not clear that omitting the Autotools' generated outputs is the right thing to do.  Often there are competing priorities, only some of which favor omitting them.  This question should not be answered, but instead closed as opinion-based.
